# restoring table data from cassandra snapshot don't gossip to other nodes in cluster

Tags: cassandra, snapshot

I'm restoring to a deleted table data from a cassandra snapshot.
This is what I'm doing:
Logging to first node.
Taking all files from snapshot and copying them to the table data directory.
Executing

```
nodetool refresh <keyspace> <table>
```

and data is showed ok on that node, but not transmitted to others in cluster.
I'm aware the reason may be related to timestamps on records, so using advice I try deleting data on tables, executing

```
TRUNCATE <table>
```

on node previously to this process, but with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a nodetool repair -full   on the other nodes?

You will need to do the same refresh process on all the nodes, so the table should appear on all the nodes after that.

Answer (score 0):

I know is a quick and dirty solution, but when I face this problem my solution was:

```
COPY Usuario (id , usuarioId, organizacionId, descripcion, estado , ultimoCambio, json , sesion) TO 'Usuario.csv';
COPY Usuario (id , usuarioId, organizacionId, descripcion, estado , ultimoCambio, json , sesion) FROM 'Usuario.csv';
```

And I prefer backup these csv than snapshots. Doing this process, rows are recreated and correctly copied to every node in cluster.

Comment: sstableloader (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html) could give you also the same functionality.